# strange nginx route resolution

Tags: nginx

I installed a fresh ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS on a VM, then nginx (nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)) serving (for a while) at http://164.67.176.22/ .

the server config file is default, with addition only of /wth:

```
server {
      listen 80 default_server;
      listen [::]:80 default_server;

      root /var/www/html;
      index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
      server_name _;

      location / {
              try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
      }

      location /wth {
               root /var/www/fcgi-bin/;
               index wth-root.html;
      }               
}
```

I restarted the server and made sure that `/var/www/fcgi-bin/wth-root.html` is properly accessible.

- now try `http://164.67.176.22/wth`, which nginx should resolve to `/var/www/fcgi-bin/wth-root.html`. However, this causes a 404 error.
- now try `http://164.67.176.22/wth-root.html`, which nginx should *not* resolve to
  anything, much less `/var/www/fcgi-bin/wth-root.html`, but it does resolve to this file.

could someone please explain to me what is going on?  (I want to understand this for playing later with fcgi, but if I can't even understand basic resolution, I have a problem.)  Is this a bug in nginx?